# Clustering of WSO2 EMM with redundant database

Tags: wso2-iot

Before I blindly run into a wall and unnecessarily break my teeth, are the guides which are available on WSO2 about clustering applicable to EMM?

I have managed to build so far a backend percona mysql-cluster, fronted by 2 haproxies but only one WSO2 EMM-server. I would like to extend this setup with at least 2 ELBs and 2 EMMs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can follow the same. It is applicable.